# A problem of relative time when two observers in different frame of reference try to calculate the time experienced by another object

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

[image]

From what I understand from special relativity the time of the one which accelerated to attain that velocity runs slower.

Let three observers be together and the three observers be A,B and C from fig 1. Let the two     observers B and C reach a velocity v by accelerating instantaneously and move towards right
with that velocity from fig 2. After some time B decelerate instantaneously and reach velocity zero with respect to A from fig 3. Now when A looks at B the time is running at
the same speed for B as for A. Now when A looks at C according to A the time of C is running slower than A because C was the one who accelerated to reach the velocity. Now
when C looks at B B is the one who accelerated to reach the velocity which B has now with respect to C. So the time of B is running slower than C. So it is contradicting because
when A looks at the time of B the time of B is running at the same speed as that of A but
when C look at B the time of B is running slower than C. And when A looks at C the time of
C is running slower than A.

It can't be like that. If the speed of running of time A,B and C is denoted by t1,t2,t3.
Then
t1 = t2
t1 > t3
t2 < t3
This can't be the case.

Comment: You are making a standard beginner's mistake. Time dilation tells you that each of A and C think the other has a slow clock. Without a round trip you cannot compare the clocks, and for a round trip you need acceleration. That is where the directionality comes in.

Answer (score 0):

You are making the mistake of thinking that time dilation means that a clock in one frame runs more slowly than a clock in another, which is just not true. All good clocks in SR run at the same rate. What time dilation means is that the duration of the gap between two events that occur in the same place in one frame is always shorter than the duration in any other frame in which they occur in two places. Put another way, the time that elapses on a single clock in one frame will be less than the differences in the readings of two separated clocks it passes in another frame.  In your thought experiment you are not comparing the time of one clock in one frame with the time on two separate clocks it passes in another, so you should not be surprised if you reach nonsensical conclusions.

In your fig 2, B and C are time dilated in the frame of A, and A is time dilated to exactly the same extent in the frame of B and C.

In your fig 3, A and B are time dilated in the frame of C, and C is time dilated to exactly the same extent in the frame of A and B.

In fig 3, the clock of B will appear to have lost time relative to A immediate following B's deceleration.